# Missing initializer in destructing declaration / identifier 'name' has already been declared [mysql][nodejs]

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, express, nodemon

When I try to insert keys as params i receve this errors on nodemon:
SyntaxError: Identifier 'name' has already been declared

this is my function on model:

```
const create = async (name, about, site) => {
    const sql = 'INSERT INTO client (name, about, site) VALUES (?, ?, ?)', [name, about, site];
    const [result] = await connection.execute(sql);
    return result;
};
```

and my route:

```
router.post('/', async (req, res) => {
  const { name, about, site } = req.body;
  const data = await create(name, about, site);
  res.status(200).json(data);
})
```

this is my first crud. how i resolve this errors?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot assign both the SQL string and the parameters array to *one* constant `sql`. What you probably mean is

```js
const create = async (name, about, site) => {
  const [result] = await connection.execute(
    'INSERT INTO client (name, about, site) VALUES (?, ?, ?)',
    [name, about, site]
  );
  return result;
};
```

Comment: I was coming back here to comment that I found the error. Was exactly this. Thank you!